# terminal doesn't use correct python version in virtual environment

Tags: python, virtualenv, conda, python-3.6, miniconda

I have created a miniconda virtual environment

```
conda create --name finalenv python=3.6
```

Now when I activate it:

```
conda activate finalenv
```

and check:

```
python --version
```

It says:

```
2.7.16
```

Even though I created a virtual environment with python 3.6 version. This is in my Visual Studio Code Terminal. How can I fix this?

If I check `python --version`outside the virtual env, it's `3.8.10`.

For example, if I try to install a particular library outside the virtual env, it works fine but throws an error if I run the same command inside the virtualenv since over there, the terminal is using an old python version @Samuel

Comment: What do you get if you type `conda list python` in your environment?

Comment: It says python version ```3.6.13``` but the terminal doesn't use it and then I am am unable to install some stuff @Ale

Comment: Have you tried reinstalling python on your system? Your entire Python version might be outdated.

Comment: If I check ```python --version```outside the virtual env, it's ```3.8.10```. For example, if I try to install a particular library outside the virtual env, it works fine but throws an error in the virtualenv since it's using an old python version @Samuel

Comment: Maybe you don't have Python 3.6 installed? Try creating an evrionment with 3.8.10 and see if that works

Comment: Please don't rollback tag changes without requesting an explanation from the editor. While OP uses the term "virtualenv" colloquially to mean "virtual environment", the tag refers to the Python package [`virtualenv`](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/latest/), which is an alternative virtual environment management system to Conda. Also, this question is not about any specific Python version (e.g., about a version-specific language feature) but about managing which interpreter gets picked up in an IDE.

Answer (score 0):

In VScode do the following:

1. File -> Preferences -> Settings
2. Search for "python.pythonPath"
3. Change path to where you usually run python from (where python 3.6.13 is located on your machine)